# Concurrent update and retrieving using spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, concurrency

I'm building an web application using Spring MVC+REST. I have some HTTP requests that update the state of the user and other that retrieve his state.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity answer(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, @RequestParam("correct") Boolean result, Principal principal) throws JsonProcessingException, InterruptedException{
    Competence comp = competenceservice.findById(id);
    User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    interactionService.registerInteraction(comp, result, user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/dailygoal/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public HttpEntity<DailyGoal> getDailyGoal(Principal principal) {
    Long goal = userservice.getDailyGoal(principal.getName());
    Long achieved = userservice.getGoalAchieved(principal.getName());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new DailyGoal(goal, achieved), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I'm trying to keep them as independent as possible, but I'm having a problem: there are some situations when I make a request to update the user state and after that a retrieve his updated state (using another request), but, due to concurrency problems (I think), sometimes I get the state not updated. I've been thinking in two possible solutions:

- 1 - To force serialization in the front-end: the second request must wait for the first request's response.
  I don't like that solution because it forces a rule to the front-end because of a back-end limitation.
- 2 - To force serialization in the back-end: the updated state of the user is the response to the update request;I don't like that solution because it doesn't respect independency of requests.

Is there something important in one of the options that I have not considered? Does someone know a (better) third option?

Comment: What about update and retrieve using one call only?

Comment: That is the second option.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is perfect. This is because you will always want the user to view the updated data as and when he is updating the data.

Consider this if I am updating a field I want to see the result or error in case there is some consistency issues so that I can take corrective action. I can only do this once update has returned with either a 200 OK a 4XX or a 5XX. Hence you should always wait for the update response and based on the response only decide what to do next.